# Permutation Group Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Hi I have an exercise in book, i.e.

Let $P \in S_n$ be a subgroup of prime order and suppose $x \in S_n$ normalizes but does not centralize P. Show that $x$ fixes at most one point in each orbit of $P$.

I understand the first sentence. But i don't know where to start to answer the question. Any hint ?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Martin Isaacs : Algebra A Graduate Course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that any $x\in S_n$ will have a fixed point in its action on $P$ by conjugation, namely $e$ (the identity element).

So we have to look at the orbits of $x$ on $P-\{e\}$. Now, since $P$ is of prime order it is cyclic, and if $x$ has a fixed point $\alpha\in P-\{e\}$ then $x\alpha = \alpha x$ and we might assume without loss of generality that $P=\langle \alpha\rangle$. Can you complete the proof?

Comment: Sorry Sir, i don't understand. How can we know that $x$ fixes at most one point in each orbit of $P$?

Comment: Let $O = \gamma^P$ be an orbit of $P$. Suppose w.l.o.g. $\gamma^x=\gamma$ and $\gamma^{\alpha x} = \gamma^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in P-\{e\}$, then you can show that $\alpha x = x\alpha$. Do you see how it relates to it now?

Comment: do you mean $\gamma^{x} =  (x)^{-1} \gamma (x)$?? then we have

$\gamma^{ \alpha x} = \gamma^{\alpha} \iff (\alpha x)^{-1} \gamma (\alpha x) = \alpha^{-1} \gamma \alpha \iff (\alpha x)^{-1} \gamma (\alpha x) = \alpha^{-1} (x^{-1} \gamma x) \alpha $
So, we have $(\alpha x)^{-1} \gamma (\alpha x) = (x \alpha)^{-1} \gamma (x \alpha) \iff \alpha x = x \alpha$?

And then what?

Comment: @NightShadow well, from that you just use what i mentioned before. if you centralise element different than the identity, then you centralise all elements. By assumption $x$ does not centralise all elements. So it can only centralise one point.

Comment: okay, thankyou for the explanation.